# Car unlocks itself

Tags: ford, central-locking

I have Ford Territory 2010 and recently it started unlocking itself. 
Changed body controller as per Ford service advice but it did not help - It locks, but later I find it unlocked.

Comment: Do you have /use the remotes?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have the battery checked to ensure it is not only fully charged, but has capacity as well.

Comment: Yes, I am using remotes to lock the car. Battery should be fine as changed not far ago, still under warranty.

Comment: take the battery out of the remote for awhile and see if it stops. maybe its bad and sending signal sometimes.

Comment: If it unlocks immediately it may be one or more of the locks themselves, or any sensors that detect the lock state (if they exist, they are usually built into the locking motor/mechanism). This results in a quick lock-unlock sound as it thinks one of the doors is ajar or has otherwise failed to lock.

Comment: No, it unlocks in some times, never immoderately. Could not catch a moment when it unlocks. Sometimes in half day, sometimes in half an hour, few days working fine and then starts playing up again.

Comment: Sorry, was meant to say never immediately